# Updating a gtk_tree_view from pthreads

Tags: gtk, gtktreeview

I've been trying to figure out some method to cause a **GtkTreeView** to redraw after I update the bound **GtkListStore** from a background thread created with **pthreads**.

Generally, the widget does not update until something obscures an existing row (even a mouse cursor ).

Most of my searches for this problem has "your tree model doesn't/isn't generating the correct signals" ....

I'm running an old Red Hat 9 with gtk+ 2.0.0, for industrial embedded applications.  Most of the data comes from ipc/socket/pipes and gets displayed by a GTK app.  Unfortunately so does CRITICAL alarms, which has a habit of not showing when they should.  We will (one day) move to a current kernel, but I need to get something working with the existing software.

I've tried emiting the *"row-changed"* signals, tried calling the **gtk_widget_queue_draw** and also tried connecting to the *"expose-event"*, where I've tried various things that don't work or seg fault.

### server.c

```
bool Server::Start()
{
 // .... 
 // pthread_t _id;
 //
 pthread_create( & _id, NULL, &StaticServerThread, this );
 // ....
}
```

### viewer.c

```
bool Viewer::ReadFinished( SocketArgs * args )
{
 gdk_threads_enter();

 // Populate the buffer and message
 //
 // GtkListStore *_outputStore;
 // gchar        *buffer;
 // gchar        *message;

 GtkTreeIter iter;
 gtk_list_store_insert_with_values( _outputStore, &iter, 0, 
                    0, buffer, 1, message, -1 );

 // ....
 gdk_threads_leave();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that GDK threads supports interoperating with plain old pthreads (even though GDK threads uses pthreads on Linux); did you try with `g_thread_create` and friends?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the updates to the list store in the main thread.  For example, you can use g_idle_add() in the worker thread.